# Adding hyperlink to a button - jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created button using jquery ui and want to add hyperlink to it , i want it to open another webpage how can this be done ?

```
$('#home').button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-home"
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `#home` element has to take care of the action itself. You can use an `anchor` tag or an `input type='submit'` both of which would have a default action.

HTML

`<a href="http://anotherwebpage" id="home">link</a>`